# ServiceStack alike request logger for WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, servicestack

Is there a simple way of implementing something like this but in the old Web Forms app in order to track ALL incomming requests with all parameters as well.

```
   Plugins.Add(new RequestLogsFeature
                {
                    RequestLogger = new CsvRequestLogger(),
                });
```

I mean, I can always write an additional HttpModule, but I was wondering if there's some better \ existing solution instead of re-inventing the wheel.